# How to test if a variable is a negative number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

First post, feedback appreciated!

I am new to python and currently working my way through 'Automate the Boring Stuff' when I stumpled upon an exercise about error-handling.
In the exercise I have to account for people not typing a **int** value in the response to the **input()**, which is where the **try:** --> **except:** comes in handy. BUT, what if I wanted to print a message when a *negativ* **int** value is inserted?

My code below prints the **except** line.

```
print('How many cats do you have')
numCats = input()

try:
    if int(numCats) >= 4:
        print('That is a lot of cats')
    elif numCats < 0:
        print('Did you give cats away you did not own?')
    else:
        print('That is not taht many cats')
except:
    print('You did not enter a number.')
```

Comment: You forgot to convert the input to a number. `numCats < 0` should be `int(numCats) < 0`.

Comment: Thank you @Aran-Fey! Always those _little_ buggers that gets me!

Comment: [ask user for input until valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) - its imho better to convert to int once and then check - not to convert every time on each if condition.

Comment: Just implemented what you shared, worked like a charm. Thank you @PatrickArtner!

Comment: Don’t use bare `except:`; it catches special exceptions that you shouldn’t suppress.  Make `try` blocks as small as possible (here, `try: numCats=int(numCats)` is enough), putting any other code that depends on it in an `else` block.  And for debugging, just don’t catch anything so you get the full error and traceback.